# weird logged in issue

Tags: php, laravel, codeigniter, session

There are two websites on one domain say `w1` and `w2`.(even DB are different)

`w1` is in CodeIgniter  `https://www.example.com/w1/` 
`w2` in laravel         `https://www.example.com/w2/`

One user has an account on one `website(w1)`, but he logged in directly to `w2`.

Is there any session conflict or another issue
What is the root cause of such an issue?

I asked the user that this is not possible, but he sent me screenshots of this scenario.

Comment: debug user session(session that's create on user login ) on both website. because your domain is same that's why your session will access on both website and possible conflict on similar session name

Comment: Sure it's possible. Looking at the URL's, the two sites share the _same_ domain, (they only have different folders, not domains) and does therefor share cookies and sessions. Check that you're using different cookie and session names for the user handling and it shouldn't be an issue. Or put the sites under their own domain names.

Comment: the best solution is: you should used sub-domain like website1: `https://w1.example.com/` and website2: `https://w2.example.com/`

Comment: could use database sessions for codeigniter one. just a thought; quick and easy.

Answer (score 0):

**It is possible.**
As your two sites are under one domain, they both get Cookie and session values in every request coming from the browser. And if you have used the same key name in the session to store the logged in user, they your code would pass the user to access inner pages which should be accessed only for a valid logged in user.

**What you should do?**
You just need to change the parent level key of the session variable in which you store the logged in user's details and which you are checking to verify the logged in user in an `IF` condition.
This should solve this problem.

**Best approach**
There are two better options to avoid this:

1) Set both of the sites under different domains.

2) At least set them under different sub-domains.